# Horowitz-Thompson estimators explained simply

Tags: survey-weights

In my current assignment I'm supposed to implement a method using GREG-estimators. In order to understand those, I'm looking at Horwitz-Thompson estimators. These I think are described in quite vague terms:

[image]

Is this a reasonable explanation and what does this mean exactly? In the simplest case with independent random sampling with an inclusion probability of $\frac{1}{N}$, it seems to follow that the inverse of this probability must be $\frac{N}{1}$, in which case the expression would resolve to:

$$Y_{HT}=\sum{Ny_i}=N\sum{y_i}$$

I assume we are trying to estimate the total value of say, car sales, for the population. But if we go about is this way we would end up with an estimated number equal to N times the total number of car sales in our sample. Obviously, that wouldn't be a good estimator of anything.

It feels like I'm missing something, so am I interpreting this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

That's not really how inclusion probability works in survey sampling. What we are calculating is the probability of the observation being chosen in "any" of the samples, so:

$$p=1-(1-\frac{1}{N})^n$$

where $N$ is the total population size and $n$ is the sample size.

Calculating this algebraically can be cumbersome, but we can use known quantities to show that the end results aren't unreasonable.

Let's define $N$ as being 10 million, and our $n$ as being 20 000.

In this case $p=1-(1-\frac{1}{N})^n=1-(1-\frac{1}{10000000})^{20000}=0.001998001$

Let's say every single person in our sample has bought three cars. In this case our previous expression for the Horowitz-Thompson estimator can be written as:

$$Y_i=\sum{d_iy_i=\sum{\frac{1}{0.001998001}}}*3=20000*\frac{1}{0.001998001}*3=30030009$$

....Indicating that 30 million cars would have been sold in our country. While we haven't proved the value of the estimator algebraically, at least it seems to make sense given the data in our example.